# MS SQL query hint FAST for read XML

Tags: sql-server, performance, openxml, hint

I have followed code in my stored procedure:

```
    SELECT
        ID,
        <..some other columns>
    INTO #MyTable
    FROM OPENXML(@hXML, N'/Root//Element', 2)
    WITH (
        ID int,
        <..some other columns with types>)
```

When I checked execution plan I found that:

1. Estimated Cost 77,5%
2. Estimatd Rows 10 000
3. Estimated IO Cost 78,7%

My xml data usually contains not 2-5 items.
When I user SQL hint FAST(10) then I can see estimation value near 0.

Should I use this hint? Does it help SQL Server perform query faster in some way?

Comment: why have you added the openxml tag? I don't see any usage of open xml in your code.

Comment: In which way should I post list or dataset from C# code to my stored procedure? I use xml and than OPENXML.